# Sticky header animating in from the left on Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, header

I'm using a sticky header and everything is fine, but, in Safari it animates in from the top left hand side when i scroll. It doesn't happen in firefox or chrome.. any idea of what you add or change in the code to make this go away and just slide down or fade in and not swoop animated in from the left?

```
// Sticky Header - Home
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
        $('#header-home').addClass("sticky");
    }
    else{
        $('#header-home').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

you can see the test site here [view in safari to see issue..]:

http://www.sdchamber.org.php53-11.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Being on Linux I can't test this, but I suspect your header being the
>   problem. See, you're giving `.header-home.sticky` a `width` of `100%`
>   and a `position:fixed` , but it has no horizontal starting point, so
>   it just animates it from the left. Adding:
>
> ```
> .header-home.sticky {
>   left: 0;
>   right: 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Would make a lot of sense to me.

This doesn't work indeed. Actually at work now and since we have OS X I decided to test it for you. This does in fact work!

```
.header.header-home {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Safari, I am getting a bunch of errors in the console. Chrome is very forgiving when it comes to CSS syntax error. Safari not so much.
Have a look and you might find your issue.

```html
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (helpers.css, line 401)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (helpers.css, line 401)
[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.css, line 3497)
[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.css, line 6166)
[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: : (bootstrap.css, line 6176)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: ; (style.css, line 764)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2512)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2546)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2658)
[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: !important (style.css, line 2815)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (owl.carousel.css, line 91)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (owl.carousel.css, line 115)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: ; (style.css, line 764)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2512)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2546)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (style.css, line 2658)
[Warning] Unexpected CSS token: !important (style.css, line 2815)
```

Comment: thanks, there we actually only two errors in there, the rest are indeed valid rules/exceptions and unfortunately not what is causing the animation from the left. but i've fixed the two so thanks for the heads up on those :)